# Is it possible to superpose two trigonometric functions to different angles?

Tags: trigonometry

I was asked to find if the function f(t) = sin ɷt - cos ɷt is periodic.

I solved it the following way :-

it's of the form sin x - sin y = 2 cos (x +y/2) sin (x-y/2)

sinɷt  - sin (Π/2-ɷt) = 2 cos (Π/4) sin (2ɷt -Π/2)

## = 2 cos (Π/4) 1/2 sin(ɷt -Π/4)

## =cos(Π/4) sin (ɷt -Π/4)

= root 2 sin (ɷt -Π/4)

I have the feeling that I've done something wrong in the last few steps. And is it possible to superimpose 2 functions (sin and cos here) with different values of angles for eg here cos is pi/4 and sin (ɷt -Π/4)

Comment: Use $\sin A-\cos A=\sqrt2\sin\left(A-\dfrac\pi4\right)$

Comment: I was following the steps mentioned in my textbook, thanks I could really use this formula but I wanted to know if the steps I followed were correct :)

Comment: We have reached at the same  expression

Comment: Is that to say I could superimpose two trig functions with different angles?

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin(x)_%2B_b_cos(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of mistakes in your derivation. I really have no idea how you actually ended up with a correct final answer.

We start with
\begin{align}
f(t) &= \sin \omega t - \cos \omega t\\
&=1\cdot\sin \omega t +(-1)\cdot \cos \omega t
\end{align}

Suppose we can write $f(t)$ in the form $A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$.

We have
\begin{align}
f(t) &=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)\\
&=A\cos(\phi)\sin(\omega t)+A\sin(\phi)\cos(\omega t)
\end{align}

Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthogonal (don't bother about this term if you don't get it), we can compare coefficients.

So
$$A\cos(\phi)=1 \tag{1}$$
and
$$A\sin(\phi)=-1 \tag{2}$$

Using $(1)^2+(2)^2$, we have
\begin{align}
A^2(\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi))&=1^2+(-1)^2\\
A^2=2\\
A=\sqrt2
\end{align}
for positive $A$.

Then we know that
So
$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$
and
$$\sin(\phi)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

Hence, with $\frac{(1)}{(2)}$,
$$\tan\phi=-1$$
so
$$\phi=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Therefore we have
$$f(t) =\sqrt2\sin\left(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
which is indeed periodic.

---

Your understanding of 'superposition' is already correct. At every $x$ value, you add the $y$ value of each individual curve together to get another curve.

[image]

So for this diagram, the yellow curve, and the red curve add up to form the blue curve.

---

Let me label your original work this way for easy reference:

\begin{align}
\sin\omega t - \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\omega t\right) 
&= 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \sin \left(2\omega t -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tag{1}\\
&= 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \cdot \frac12 \sin\left(\omega t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \sin \left(\omega t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\tag{3}\\
&= \sqrt2 \sin \left(\omega t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\tag{4}\\
\end{align}

$(1)$ is correct. There's no problem with that.

$(2)$ is wrong. Note that $$\sin \left(2\omega t -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\neq\frac12 \sin\left(\omega t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ In general, $$\sin 2x =2\sin x \cos x\neq 2\sin x \neq \frac12 \sin x$$

$(3)$ and $(4)$ on their own are correct but a major mistake is already made at $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, but I still have this one doubt what does it mean to superpose? Is it adding two trig functions for the same angle ?

Comment: Could you tell me where I went wrong in my derivation? I liked your approach but it'd be really helpful to know what went wrong :)

Comment: @JacobP.J Hi, sorry I just came back from something. Is it okay if I do this tomorrow? It's kinda of late in my time zone right now.

Comment: its k :) thank u